# Build f-strings from normal strings

Tags: python, python-3.6, f-string

I'm trying the new f-strings, and I'm wondering if it's possible to "compile" a normal string into an f-string.
So to have control on the evaluation time of the f-string, and be capable of defining f-strings before consuming them.

Example pseudo-code:

```
a = 'normal string with some curly {inside}'
inside = 'in it!'
print(a.make_f_string())
>>> 'normal string with some curly in it!'
```

So basically my need is to define the f-string before the variable that it contains. or make a string an f-string.

I tried to play with the [nesting capabilities of them (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215365/nested-f-strings) but with no luck.

Is it possible? So far the only way I found is with eval(), and seems far from a good way to do it.

```
eval(f"f'{a}'")
```

Comment: Is `a.format(**locals())` sufficient?

Comment: yes it is, so it is a.map_format(locals()), I'm just playing around and studying f-strings and see what they can do, haw they can be used..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible?

No, apart from `eval`ing or `exec`ing in a similar fashion, you can't do this.

Since you are trying to define a format before actual formatting is needed, you need `.format`, not `f`-strings.