# Use of variable defined f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fairly often I use the `string.format()` for insertion of key-value pairs into a string template. The new [Pep 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) f-strings have been recommended for a while but they seem to be a terrible choice for this behavior.

For instance if I wish to create a new f_string I need to make the variable first:

```
>>> date = 22
>>> date2 = f'this is a {date}'
>>> date2
'this is a 22'
```

Now if I try and perform the same action by creating an `f-string` template but without having the replacement value initialized I get the expected `NameError`

```
>>> date_template = f'this is a new {date_new}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'date_new' is not defined
```

As there is no way to convert a string to [f-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780515/build-f-strings-from-normal-strings) and `f-strings` appear to be mainly syntatic sugar. Is there a non-obvious way of using `f-strings` as templates or should I continue using `string.format()` and `string.format_map()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to postpone/defer the evaluation of f-strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497625/how-to-postpone-defer-the-evaluation-of-f-strings)

Answer (score 0):

#### At the moment, there does not seem to be any better way than `str.format` and `str.format_map`.

After searching the [Index of Python Enhancement Proposals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/), I found these two relevent PEPs: [PEP 501](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0501) (General purpose string interpolation) and [PEP 502](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0502) (String Interpolation - Extended Discussion). PEP 501 has been deferred with [this note](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0501/#pep-deferral) in the PEP document:

> This PEP is currently deferred pending further experience with PEP 498's simpler approach of only supporting eager rendering without the additional complexity of also supporting deferred rendering.

I have not found any information about future plans regarding PEP 501.

---

#### There is a way to get around *some* of the limitations of `locals()` mentioned [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#no-use-of-globals-or-locals).

In the following example, when `f1` is called it throws a `KeyError` because `locals()` returns a `dict` with all the variables in the scope of `f2`, which does not contain `x`.

```py
def f1():
    x = 4
    def f2():
        return 'x={x}'.format_map(locals())
    return f2()
```

When a variable defined in an outer scope is not used in a function, the interpreter will not waste resources including that variable in a closure. The interpreter cannot tell that `x` actually **is** used in `f2` because that use is specified in the string, where the interpreter does not check for variable usage. Because `x`  does not appear to be used in `f2`, it is discarded when `f1` returns to save memory.

We can override this behavior by explicitly using `x` in `f2`.

```py
def f1():
    x = 4
    def f2():
        x
        return 'x={x}'.format_map(locals())
    return f2()
```

Note: if `x` is already used in `f2` there is no need to mention it again. For example:

```py
def f1():
    x = 4
    def f2():
        print(x)
        return 'x={x}'.format_map(locals())
    return f2()
```

The (somewhat pointless) call to `print` here uses `x` so there is no need to explicitly use it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - f-strings have to be hard-coded in the source where the values they use are defined. For templates, there are the `.format` and `.format_map` string methods. And actually, there is no way to avoid this that would make sense in the language.

On the other hand, it works flawlessly, the drawback being that f-strings allow for inlined Python arbitrary expressions, and templates designed to be used with `.format` can only replace a variable name for its value.