# Is nested string literal interpolation possible?

Tags: python, string, python-3.6

When using [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals), it is possible to have nested *f-strings* to some extent.

```
a = 3
b = 7

res = f"{f'{a*b}'}"

print(res) # '21'
```

Although, the same does not work if the inner expression is a variable containing a string.

```
a = 3
b = 7

expr = 'a*b'

res = f"{f'{expr}'}"

print(res) # 'a*b'
```

Is there a way to make this work and to have the second output to be `'21'` as well? If not, what is the difference between the first and second string that prevents it?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are wondering if you can get the second to output 21?

Comment: @user3483203 Yes, let me add that in the question

Comment: Maybe you can put an `eval` in, i.e. `res = f"{f'{eval(expr)}'}"`

Comment: If anyone posts an answer with eval they are getting downvoted.

Comment: @user3483203 Seems my comment should have been posted 35 seconds later for proper irony

Comment: @user3483203 I take you up on that bet and raise you two options

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41215365/8033585

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be helpful to see what is actually happening under the hood when each of these expressions is called.

### `f"{f'{a*b}'}"`

```
def om1(a, b):
    return f"{f'{a*b}'}"

dis.dis(om1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              8 FORMAT_VALUE             0
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

The outer *f-string* encounters an expression which it evaluates, and the inner *f-string* also finds an expression which it evaluates, which results in the call to `BINARY_MULTIPLY`

### `f"{f'{expr}'}"`

```
def om2(a, b):
    expr = 'a*b'
    return f"{f'{expr}'}"

dis.dis(om2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a*b')
              2 STORE_FAST               2 (expr)

  3           4 LOAD_FAST                2 (expr)
              6 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              8 FORMAT_VALUE             0
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here, the first *f-string* encounters an expression and evaluates it, and the inner *f-string*, encounters a string, resulting in the call to `LOAD_FAST` instead of evaluating the contents of the string as Python code.

Also it is important to note in this second example the missing `LOAD_FAST` calls to both `a` and `b`, which are present in the first example.

Comment: It is a good idea to display the bytecode. This answer has been really helpful, but would not have been quite sufficient if it was not for the key fact, given in @Amadan answer, that f-string code is generated at compile time, not at runtime and that it *does not* rely on calling an eval. If I could acceot both answers I would as it is combined that they give the best explanation.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few libraries that have developed functions for evaluating numerical and logical expressions *safely* ("safe" being the key).

First, the setup -

```
a = 3
b = 7
op = '*'
```

#### `numexpr.evaluate`

```
>>> import numexpr as ne
>>> ne.evaluate(f'{a} {op} {b}')
array(21, dtype=int32)
```

[`numexpr`](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is smart enough to optimise your expressions, and is even faster than numpy in some instances. Install using `pip`.

---

#### `pandas.eval`

A *safe* eval from the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) API similar to `ne.evaluate`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.eval(f'{a} {op} {c}')
12
```

Comment: Wasn't it you on a question 10 minutes ago that took an oath to downvote anything using eval?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon builtin `eval`, yes. And I still will

Comment: That's fair, I am more interested in knowing *why* it cannot be done with f-strings if it actually cannot, but your answer is interesting. Why is pandas.eval considered safe?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Why doesn't it work? I'm not sure, but I can answer the second question. `pandas.eval` actually has code to parse expressions it receives, and it is strict about the kinds of operations it considers valid and what not. For example, import statements to `pd.eval` are a strict no-no.

Answer (score 2):

It's called "string *literal* interpolation". The string must be a literal, i.e. at the time the compilation takes place compiler will turn the string into a proper executable code. If you already have a string as a value (not as a literal), it's too late for that.

I don't have access to Python that has PEP 498 enabled, so my examples will be in Ruby, which has had this mechanism for a long time. The Ruby syntax for Python's `f"...{expr}..."` is `"...#{expr}..."`.

In Ruby, `"a#{2 * 3}b"` is syntactic sugar for `["a", (2 * 3), "b"].join` (as in, they produce exactly the same bytecode). If you have the string `"2 * 3"` already as a value, the compiler can't do anything about it; the only way to turn a string value into a result is to evaluate it.

In the first example, you have a string literal inside a string literal; both are processed by the compiler at compile time: when the compiler sees the outer literal, it compiles it, finds another string literal there, compiles that as well, produces code. As a matter of fact, `"a#{"#{2 * 3}"}b"` produces exactly the same byte code, again.

The fact that this is done at compile time is also the reason why string literal interpolation will raise a syntax error if the expression inside is malformed, even if the line in question is never executed: `if false; "#{1+}"; end` will produce a `SyntaxError`.

The fact that this is done at compile time means strings already in variables are not eligible for this mechanism. In your code, by the time `res` is evaluated, `expr` could have been anything; the only way out is `evil` (or another, safer, evaluator).