# Python - using format/f string to output hex with 0 padding AND center

Tags: python

I'm attempting to output an integer as a hex with 0 padding AND center it.

```
data = 10
```

I can do one or the other:

```
'{:#04x}'.format(data) # my attempt at PADDING
'{:^#14x}'.format(data) # Centers Correctly
```

I can't figure out how to combine the two
the Output I want is:

```
0x0a  # centered in a width of 14
```

Comment: Format the data twice: first by padding and hex formatting, then a second time with centering. I think this will make it easier to understand what is going on anyway.

Comment: `'{:^14s}'.format('{:#04x}'.format(data))`

Comment: This reminds me of a need I had in a templating function to pass in the width I was padding strings to. Slightly different solution here than there, but it ended up being the (rather sly) `"{{:>{}.2f}}".format(width).format(num)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since Python 3.6+ with an [f string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0536/):

```
>>> '{:^14s}'.format(f'0x{data:02x}')
'     0x0a     '
```

Which can be (perhaps [abusively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215365/nested-f-strings)) shortened to:

```
>>> f'{f"0x{data:02x}":^14}'
'     0x0a     '
```

And perhaps a little more straightforwardly:

```
>>> f'{format(data, "#04x"):^14}'
'     0x0a     '
```

---

With Python<3.6:

```
>>> '{:^14s}'.format('{:#04x}'.format(data))
'     0x0a     '
```

Comment: "perhaps" abusively ;)

Comment: It is debatable whether nested f strings are intended, but this is a example of a good use.

Comment: @IceflowerS: I just retested all four examples on Python 3.10 and all produce the output described. What do you mean 'this does not work?'

Comment: MacOS Python 3.10.0 Oct 22, 2021. That string `>>> '{:^14s}'.format(f'{data:#02x}')
` produces `'     0xa      '`. Maybe try breaking into constituent parts? What happens with `'{:^14s}'.format("X")` for example?

Comment: @IceflowerS: Don't know how to comment on something I cannot reproduce. It works on MacOS and Linux with Python 3.8-3.10.

Comment: the last edit of your post by @hans-ginzel made the output wrong.

Comment: I rolled it back

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit ugly but works fine:

```
'{:^14}'.format('{:#04x}'.format(data))
```