# Using f String to insert characters or symbols @

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two variables that store two numbers in total.
  I want to combine those numbers and separate them with a comma. I read that I can use {variablename:+} to insert a plus or spaces or a zero but the comma doesn't work.

```
x = 42
y = 73
print(f'the number is {x:}{y:,}')
```

here is my weird solution, im adding a + and then replacing the + with a comma. Is there a more direct way?

```
x = 42
y = 73
print(f'the number is {x:}{y:+}'.replace("+", ","))
```

Lets say I have names and domain names and I want to build a list of email addresses. So I want to fuse the two names with an @ symbol in the middel and a .com at the end.

Thats just one example I  can think off the top of my head.

```
x = "John"
y = "gmail"
z = ".com"
print(f'the email is {x}{y:+}{z}'.replace(",", "@"))
```

results in:

```
print(f'the email is {x}{y:+}{z}'.replace(",", "@"))
ValueError: Sign not allowed in string format specifier
```

Comment: `f'the number is {x},{y}'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put something into **"{}"** inside f-formatting, it's actually being evaluated. So, everything which shouldn't put it outside the "{}". 
Some Examples:

```
x = 42
y = 73
print(f'Numbers are: {x}, {y}') # will print: 'Numbers are: 42, 73'
print(f'Sum of numbers: {x+y}') # will print: 'Sum of numbers: 115'
```

You can even do something like:

```
def compose_email(user_name, domain):
      return f'{user_name}@{domain}'

user_name = 'user'
domain = 'gmail.com'
print(f'email is: {compose_email(user_name, domain)}')

>>email is: user@gmail.com
```

For more examples see: 
[Nested f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215365/nested-f-strings)

Answer (score 5):

You are over-complicating things.

Since only what's between `{` and `}` is going to be evaluated, you can simply do

`print(f'the number is {x},{y}')` for the first example, and

`print(f'the email is {x}@{y}{z}')` for the second.