# Avoid duplicating arguments to str.format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format

I'm currently using string formatting in my code however I find that I'm hard coding to display repeated variables. Is there a more efficient way to do this

```
print("Hello this is {} and {} and {} - Hello this is {} and {} and {} ".format(versionP, versionS, versionT, versionP, versionS, versionT))
```

The outcome is the one I want but I need to repeat this in several instances and can become tedious. Is there a way to only write the variable once?

Comment: This depends on your Python version. F-strings, as proposed by Aaron_ab, are available from 3.6 onward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Python 3.6**

I find it clean and simple:

```
print(f"Hello this is {versionP} and {versionS} and {versionT} - 
        Hello this is {versionP} and {versionS} and {versionT}")
```

You can even [evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583596/using-f-string-to-insert-characters-or-symbols/53583674#53583674) methods inside f-formatting or [nested f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215365/nested-f-strings)

Comment: Good answer, but this assumes OP has python3.6

Comment: Good point. This will work only in 3.6 and above.. I like your answer as well with the dictionary

Answer (score 8):

You can specify positions, and `str.format` will know which arguments to use:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
string = "This is {0}, {1}, and {2}. Or, in reverse: {2}, {1}, {0}"
string.format(a, b, c)
# 'This is 1, 2, and 3. Or, in reverse: 3, 2, 1'
```

---

You may also pass keyword arguments, or unpack a dictionary:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
string = """This is {versionP}, {versionS}, and {versionT}. 
            Or, in reverse: {versionT}, {versionS}, {versionP}"""
# string.format(versionP=a, versionS=b, versionT=c)
string.format(**{'versionP': a, 'versionS': b, 'versionT': c})
# This is 1, 2, and 3. 
#       Or, in reverse: 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: Notice the tecenique with the dictionary can raise exception when have no relevant keys in the dict to place..

Comment: Note to OP: I have converted my answer into runnable examples so you can see for yourself how this works. The process is identical for your use case.