# How to position a character before the contents of a set of curly braces using f-string

Tags: python, string, f-string

I have some code I found during a classes tutorial and I can’t understand how one line is working (although it does work).
It is the fstring line, the part in question is the “:+” at the end of the second set of curly braces, I don’t understand how the :+ can make the needed “+” in the string format appear before the contents of the curly braces when the string is outputted.

**Code**

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x_comp, y_comp):
        self.x_comp = x_comp
        self.y_comp = y_comp

    def __str__(self):
        # By default, sign of +ve number is not displayed
        # Using `+`, sign is always displayed
        return f'{self.x_comp}i{self.y_comp:+}j'
        
v = Vector(3,4)
print(str(v))

print(v)
```

**Output**

```
3i+4j
3i+4j
```

Comment: I believe including the `+` tells the string formatter to always include the number's sign when formatting as string. Normally, a positive number would not have its sign symbol (`+`) shown.

Comment: Is that why it needed a colon before it?

Comment: Yes. When using f-strings, you can put the string format after a colon within the curly braces. For example, for a floating point value you could using `{my_float_val:.3f}` to show it with 3 places after the decimal point.

Comment: I found this after reading your comment, thank you Matthew https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583596/using-f-string-to-insert-characters-or-symbols

Comment: If you paste that as an answer I’ll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the `+` tells the string formatter to always include the number's sign when formatting as string. Normally, a positive number would not have its sign symbol (`+`) shown.

- For more on f-string syntax, see [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).
- For string format specifier reference (including mention of `+`), see [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Answer (score 2):

```
'+'  - indicates that a sign should be used for both
       positive as well as negative numbers
'-'  - indicates that a sign should be used only for negative
       numbers (this is the default behavior)
' '  - indicates that a leading space should be used on
       positive numbers
```

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#standard-format-specifiers