# Trying to understand some f-string magic (formatting mini language in f-strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

In a comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215365/nested-f-strings), somebody dropped this line of code:

```
print("\n".join(f'{a:{a}<{a}}' for a in range(1,10)))
```

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

And it looks like magic to me, can somebody explain to me why it works (more specifically `f'{a:{a}<{a}}'`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple if you visualize the iterations:

```
1           # f'{1:1<1}', means start with 1, left align with 1 spaces filled with 1
22          # f'{2:2<2}', means start with 2, left align with 2 spaces filled with 2
333         # f'{3:3<3}', means start with 3, left align with 3 spaces filled with 3
4444        # f'{4:4<4}', means start with 4, left align with 4 spaces filled with 4
55555       # f'{5:5<5}', means start with 5, left align with 5 spaces filled with 5
666666      # f'{6:6<6}', means start with 6, left align with 6 spaces filled with 6
7777777     # f'{7:7<7}', means start with 7, left align with 7 spaces filled with 7
88888888    # f'{8:8<8}', means start with 8, left align with 8 spaces filled with 8
999999999   # f'{9:9<9}', means start with 9, left align with 9 spaces filled with 9
```

You already know what the f-string `f'{a:{a}<{a}'` does - when given an `{object}` within the string it will replace with said object.  In this case, `a` is range of 1 to 9.

Then all you need to understand is what `{9:9<9}` does.  It's a string formatter as [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) that the answer has provided:

> `'<'` Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space (this is the default for most objects).

The `x<y` portion signifies to left-align the text with a width of `y` spaces.  For any unused space, pad it with character `x`.  So you start with `{9}` as the first character, and for the rest of the 8 unused spaces, fill it with `{9}`.  This is what `{9:9<9}` does.

Then you apply the same logic and see how each iteration came about.

More importantly, it should be noted that what feels like "magic" is often just a lack of understanding.  Once you take the time to digest and understand the process, it becomes very disillusioning and you become enlightened.

Comment: Thanks, in my head it would have printed `{1:False}` as I though it had to do with the comparison operator `<`

Comment: What's within the `{}` quote is interpreted as a string formatter.  But to add to your example, you *could* add computation within it as well.  e.g. `f'{32:0{"b" if cond else "x"}}'` will format `32` as bytes or hex depending on condition.  What's within the immediate `{}` gets evaluated first, and so the outer-most `{}` is left alone to be a string formatter to be evaluated last... if it's a valid format.

Comment: One day, I might actually use this... Thank you for the great explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You can demistify the output if you substitute some things:

```
print("\n".join(f'{a:4<5}' for a in range(1,10)))
```

and read up on [String format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

It left aligns the value of `a` in 5 spaces using `4` as filler:

```
14444
24444
34444
44444
54444
64444
74444
84444
94444
```

Playing around with code is a good way to get what it does ...