# How would I define a fill character for f-string alignment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I've been messing around with text-alignment, including the string methods, and f-strings. My current goal is to create a table of contents styled output, that looks something like this:

```
Introduction....................1
Python Basics...................5
Creating Your First Program....12
Operators and Variables........29
```

Easily enough, I've been able to format it like:

```
Introduction                    1
Python Basics                   5
Creating Your First Program    12
Operators and Variables        29
```

The code being:

```py
for chapt, page in contents:
  print(f"{chapt:<30}{page:>5}")
```

I can't find any resources on the web that describe how to add a fill character and f-strings together. Using the `.center`, `.ljust`, `.rjust` string methods, I have been able to do this, as they take the parameter of width and then an optional fill character.
On [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656033/trying-to-understand-some-f-string-magic-formatting-mini-language-in-f-strings), I thought I found a solution.

> The `x<y` portion signifies to left-align the text with a width of y spaces. For any unused space, pad it with character x.

I tried this method, editing my print statement from `print(f"{chapt:<30}{page:>5}")` to `print(f"{chapt:'.'<30}{page:'.'>5}")`. Yet this returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(f"{chapt:'.'<30}{page:'.'>5}")
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

(Line 40 being the line in my full code.)

Is there any way to choose a fill character, or would I have to revert to the string methods. I believe there is, but I can not figure out how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Specify it before the alignment character (`>` or `<`), without apostrophes.

```
contents = {"Introduction": 1, "Python Basics": 5, "Creating Your First Program": 12, "Operators and Variables": 29}
for chapt, page in contents.items():
    print(f"{chapt:.<30}{page:.>5}")
```

Outputs:

```
Introduction......................1
Python Basics.....................5
Creating Your First Program......12
Operators and Variables..........29
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

> If a valid *align* value is specified, it can be preceded by a *fill* character that can be any character and defaults to a space if omitted. It is not possible to use a literal curly brace (“`{`” or “`}`”) as the *fill* character in a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) or when using the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method. However, it is possible to insert a curly brace with a nested replacement field. This limitation doesn’t affect the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) function

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) you have to specify it before the "align":

```
contents = [('Introduction', 1), ('Python Basics', 5),
            ('Creating Your First Program', 12),
            ('Operators and Variables', 29)]

row_length = 35

for chapt, page in contents:
    dots = str(row_length - len(str(page)))
    print(f"{chapt:.<{dots}}{page}")
```

*This is now independent of the `page` number's length. A little bit more flexible.