# Dynamic padding with period using f-string

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, padding, f-string

Given a width `n`, and an index `i`, how to generate a string of length `n` with `x` at index `i`, and `.` at the remaining indices?

For example:

```
Input: n = 4, i = 1
Output: ".x.."
```

Currently I'm doing:

```
"".join("x" if j == i else "." for j in range(n))
```

Another option:

```
("." * i) + "x" + ("." * (n - i - 1))
```

I can also do:

```
f"{('.' * i)}x{('.' * (n - i - 1))}"
```

All work, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with f-string, perhaps using some form of padding, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57826337/839733)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mix of ljust and must multiplying to create a string

```
>>> f"{'.' * i}x".ljust(n, ".")
'.x..'
```

Or just using f strings alone by [specifying a separator for the alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67540852/1324033)

```
 f"{'.' * i}{'x':.<{n-i}}"
```

Comment: As shown in my question, I can do this without `ljust` - `f"{('.' * i)}x{('.' * (n - i - 1))}"`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - Updated

Comment: Upvoted, but is there a way to avoid the string replication and pad on both sides, perhaps using some combination of `>` and `<`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - None that I've been able to find... having a look though

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - `f'''{f"{'x':.<{n-i}}":.>{n}}'''` but I don't really like it (harder to read than version in answer)