# Limit complex string length using f string

Tags: python-3.x

With the following code i can interpolate a string within a limit length:

```
HEADER_LENGTH = 10
message = "Hello"

header = f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}"
```

That way `header` is a `string` with `max_length = 10`

So the return of the code will be:

```
#print(header)
>>> 5

#print(len(header))
>>> 10
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
HEADER_LENGTH = 10
message = "Hello"
word = "foo"

#just example it doesn't work
header = f"{{word} {len(message)}}:<{HEADER_LENGTH}"
```

And the expected output will be:

```
#print(header)
>>> foo 5

#print(len(header))
>>> 10
```

- There are any way to do this using f string?
- If not, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can [nest f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215365/nested-f-strings).  In your case you want this:

```
header = f"{f'{word} {len(message)}':<{HEADER_LENGTH}}"
```

But I would caution against putting too much complexity into an f-string.  It would be clearer if written separately:

```
part1 = f'{word} {len(message)}'
header = f"{part1:<{HEADER_LENGTH}}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didnt know how to search for this.