# Recursive {pattern} replacement in/using object's properties

Tags: python, recursion

I want to use an object's properties for recursive pattern replacement. Since the object's properties are not known at time of class definition I cannot use **@property decorators**

**Example**

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = '{year}-{month}'
        self.year = '2020'
        self.month = '06'

        self.path = '/dev/null'
        self.file_name = 'ABC-{date}.mp4'
        self.file = '{path}/{file_name}'

    def print(self):
        print(__class__)
        print ("Filename is {file_name}".format(**vars(self)))
        print ("File {file} will be written to {path}".format(**vars(self)))

t = Test()
t.print()
```

**Actual output**

```
<class '__main__.Test'>
Filename is ABC-{date}.mp4
File {path}/{file_name} will be written to /dev/null
```

**Desired output**

```
<class '__main__.Test'>
Filename is ABC-2020-06.mp4
File /dev/null/ABC-2020-06.mp4 will be written to /dev/null
```

Comment: It'd be interesting to see if there's a solution to this, but I doubt that there is. Nested format strings feels like it's impossible because it's just an [expression that's evaluated at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41227080/929999). But perhaps there's some voodoo I haven't seen before. Your best bet is to create a parser or something that detects `{...}` and keeps attempting to format/parse the string for as long as there's something to parse. Altho that seems hacky.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the object's properties are not known at time of class definition"*? In the example you gave, all the instance attributes are defined in `__init__`, and `Test.print` only uses attributes defined in `__init__`.

Comment: This seems like a bit of an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832), but thankfully you've included the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want advice. This is a great first question even though it's a bit unclear.

Comment: Should have clarified: This is just a simplified example, the properties in my actual code are only passed to __init__ at run time.

Comment: @Chris Oh, you mean the *values* of the attributes aren't known? That's pretty standard, and still doesn't prevent you from using properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned recursion but did not actually use any recursion in your code.

You can achieve the desired behavior by implementing a recursive method that formats a given template string until the rendered result is the same as the input:

```
def render(self, template):
    rendered = template.format(**vars(self))
    return rendered if rendered == template else self.render(rendered)

def print(self):
    print(self.render("Filename is {file_name}"))
    print(self.render("File {file} will be written to {path}"))
```

With the above changes, your code would output:

```
Filename is ABC-2020-06.mp4
File /dev/null/ABC-2020-06.mp4 will be written to /dev/null
```

Comment: Wow, so simple! I had tried other approaches with recursion before but ended up in endless loops

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use properties. You just need to use more of them than you expected.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.year = '2020'
        self.month = '06'

        self.path = '/dev/null'

    @property
    def file(self):
        return '{0.path}/{0.file_name}'.format(self)

    @property
    def file_name(self):
        return 'ABC-{0.date}.mp4'.format(self)

    @property
    def date(self):
        return '{0.year}-{0.month}'.format(self)

    def print(self):
        print(__class__)
        print ("Filename is {0.file_name}".format(self))
        print ("File {0.file} will be written to {0.path}".format(self))

t = Test()
t.print()
```

`path`, `year`, and `month` are the only "hard-coded" attributes; the rest can be derived. The recursion (such as it is) is implicit in that each attribute access may be a property which itself invokes another property. This is the key benefit of properties: their *interface* is indistinguishable from an instance attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible, by overriding `__dict__` and `__getattribute__`:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = '{year}-{month}'
        self.year = '2020'
        self.month = '06'

        self.path = '/dev/null'
        self.file_name = 'ABC-{date}.mp4'
        self.file = '{path}/{file_name}'
        self.__dict__ = {x: getattr(self, x) for x in vars(self)}

    def __getattribute__(self, a):
        real_attribute = super().__getattribute__(a)
        if isinstance(real_attribute, str) and "{" in real_attribute:
            return real_attribute.format(
                **{
                    x: getattr(self, x)
                    for x in vars(self)
                    if "{" + x + "}" in real_attribute
                }
            )
        return real_attribute
    def print(self):
        print(__class__)
        print ("Filename is {file_name}".format(**vars(self)))
        print ("File {file} will be written to {path}".format(**vars(self)))

t = Test()
t.print()
```

Comment: `self.__dict__` is set automatically, so why do you set it manually?

Comment: @wjandrea `self.__dict__` doesn’t seem to use the defined `__getattribute__`. If I run it without that line, I just get `<class '__main__.Test'>
Filename is ABC-{date}.mp4
File {path}/{file_name} will be written to /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a little [helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57632793/355230) (named `FL` below) along with [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) literals instead of the `str.format()` method. Here's what I mean:

```
class FL:
    """ Lazy literal f-string interpolation: Postpones evaluation of string
        until instance is converted to a string.
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __str__(self):
        return self.func()


class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = FL(lambda: f'{self.year}-{self.month}')
        self.year = '2020'
        self.month = '06'

        self.path = '/dev/null'
        self.file_name = FL(lambda: f'ABC-{self.date}.mp4')
        self.file = FL(lambda: f'{self.path}/{self.file_name}')

    def print(self):
        print(__class__)
        print(FL(lambda: f"Filename is {self.file_name}"))
        print(FL(lambda: f"File {self.file} will be written to {self.path}"))

t = Test()
t.print()
```