# How to fix SyntaxError: f-string: expressions nested too deeply in python 3.7.0?

Tags: python, f-string

Below is my code snippet. When running the code in python 3.7 I get the error `SyntaxError: f-string: expressions nested too deeply`. How should I refactor my code?

```
    GRAPH_QL_FIELDS = """
                cubeId
                title
                deleted
                timeVariableFormat
                statisticalProgram {
                  name
                }
                topics{
                    topicId
                }
              }
    """

    query_topics = (
                f'query cubesWithTopicLink($deleted: Boolean!, $topicId: String, $first: Int, $skip: Int) {{'
                f'dataCubes(where:{AND:[{topics_some: {{topicId: $topicId}}}, {deleted: $deleted}]}, first: $first, skip: $skip) {{'
                f'{GRAPH_QL_FIELDS}'
                f'dataCubesConnection(where: {topics_some: {topicId: $topicId}})'
                f'{{aggregate{{count}}}}'
                f'}}'
            )
```

Comment: Yes, you should refactor your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use multi-line strings `f"""This will work as expected with other nested strings '{3+5}'"""`

Answer (score -2):

You cannot nest `f-string`, like `f'{f"my_var"}'`, so you should refactor your code by removing nested f-string and dividing them into more f-string.

As stated by [Dimitris Fasarakis Hilliard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41227080/5790653):

> I don't think formatted string literals allowing nesting (by nesting, I take it to mean f'{f".."}') is a result of careful consideration of possible use cases, I'm more convinced it's just allowed in order for them to conform with their specification.

> The specification states that they [support full Python expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#supporting-full-python-expressions)* inside brackets. It's also stated that a formatted string literal is really just an expression that is evaluated at run-time (See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#abstract), and [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)). As a result, it only makes sense to allow a formatted string literal as the expression inside another formatted string literal, forbidding it would negate the full support for Python expressions.

> The fact that you can't find use cases mentioned in the docs (and only find test cases in the test suite) is because this is probably a nice (side) effect of the implementation and not it's motivating use-case.

Comment: The answer you quoted is saying that f-strings **can** be nested