# how do I put a {} inside a {} in a python formatted string?

Tags: python, string, format, currency

I am new to programing and I am trying to print:

```py
money = 5000
print(f'Your account has ${ {money:,} if money > 0 else "nothing"}.')
```

I want it to print "Your account has $5,000." but when I run it comes back as

```py
( {money:,} if money > 0 else "nothing")
         ^
SyntaxError: f-string: invalid syntax
```

yet if I do it by itself:

```py
money = 5000
print(f'Your account has ${money:,}.')

>>>Your account has $5,000.
```

it works with just one pair: { }. How can I make the first one work with two pairs: { { } }?

Comment: Your inner f-string lacks *quotes*, see examples at https://stackoverflow.com/q/41215365/3001761

Comment: jonrsharpe: this answers it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I will strongly suggest you to use this:

```
if money > 0:
    print(f'Your account has ${money:,}.')
else:
    print('Your account has nothing.')
```