# nested strings for random.choice python

Tags: python, random

I have 4 lists and want to choose a random list and then choose a random item of it. this is my code but it doesn't work properly. can you help please?

```
import random
w=['*', '&' ,'^', '%' ,'$' ,'#', '@' ,'!']
w1=['w','a','s','r','i','t','e','n','d','c']
w2=['W','A','S','R','I','T','E','N','D','C',]
w3=['1','2']

p=''
j=8
while j:
   e=random.choice(['w','w1','w2','w3'])
   q=random.choice(f'{f"{e}"}')
   p+=q
   j-=1

print(p)
```

and this is the wrong output that doesnt select from the lists:

```
w3www3ww
```

Comment: Don't make it so complicated. `e = random.choice([w, w1, w2, w3])`, then `q = random.choice(e)`.

Comment: Also, to repeat something 8 times, use `for _ in range(8)`. Don't bother decrementing counters in `while` loops.

Comment: Why exactly were you trying to make a random choice of a nested f-string of the choice you already made?

Comment: no it dosent also work properly it chooses so many w's @mkrieger1

Comment: Did you forget to change `random.choice(['w','w1','w2','w3'])` to `random.choice([w, w1, w2, w3])`?

Comment: yes tnks it worked, anyway how can we use nested format strings?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215365/nested-f-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension and nest the `random.choice` calls like so:

```py
import random

w = ['*', '&', '^', '%', '$', '#', '@', '!']
w1 = ['w', 'a', 's', 'r', 'i', 't', 'e', 'n', 'd', 'c']
w2 = ['W', 'A', 'S', 'R', 'I', 'T', 'E', 'N', 'D', 'C']
w3 = ['1', '2']

wlist = [w, w1, w2, w3]

p = ''.join(random.choice(random.choice(wlist)) for _ in range(8))

print(p)
```

Using list unpacking, you can shorten the code even more:

```py
wlist = [*w, *w1, *w2, *w3]

p = ''.join(random.choice(wlist) for _ in range(8))
```

Make sure your list contains the variables, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

w = ['*', '&', '^', '%', '$', '#', '@', '!']
w1 = ['w', 'a', 's', 'r', 'i', 't', 'e', 'n', 'd', 'c']
w2 = ['W', 'A', 'S', 'R', 'I', 'T', 'E', 'N', 'D', 'C']
w3 = ['1', '2']

p = ''
j = 8
while j:
    e = random.choice([w, w1, w2, w3])  # Choose between the lists w, w1, w2, w3
    q = random.choice(e)  # Choose a random character from the chosen list
    p += q
    j -= 1

print(p)
```